# How To Do Percent/Total in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an typical CUSTOMER/ORDERS set of tables and I want to display the total **percentage** of sales a particular customer is responsible for. I can get the total number of orders in the system like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM orders
```

And I can get the the total number of orders made by the customer like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM orders WHERE cust_id = 541
```

How can I combine these into a single query that returns the percentage of sales for a particular customer? Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

MySQL:

```
SELECT ROUND(
  100.0 * (
      SUM(IF(cust_id = 541, 1, 0)) / COUNT(order_id)
  ), 1) AS percent_total
FROM orders;
```

**Edit**

I guess it helps if I would have noticed the **postgres** tag. I thought it was a MySQL question.

PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT ROUND(
  100.0 * (
      SUM(CASE WHEN cust_id = 541 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::numeric / COUNT(order_id)
  ), 1) AS percent_total
FROM orders;
```

P.S. My PostgreSQL is rusty, so if the MySQL query works on PostgreSQL I'd like to know :)

**Edit 2**

I can't stress enough to be wary of the count(*) suggestion below. You generally want to avoid this with PostgreSQL.

Comment: why do you want to avoid count(*) in PostgreSQL?

Comment: unsure, but maybe he means that postgres will calculate the count each time, it can be an expensive operation.

Comment: At least in PostgreSql, I believe the sum needs to be casted before division using something as in (...)::DECIMAL(5,4) otherwise the division will be integer division and the result would be zero.

Comment: NoChance is correct. The solution above did not work for me (produces 0.0), but this does: `SELECT ROUND(100.0 * (SUM(CASE WHEN cust_id = 541 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)::DECIMAL / COUNT(order_id)), 1) AS percent_total FROM orders;`

Comment: Assuming `order_id` is non-null for each row in `orders` (which seems likely) then `COUNT(*)` is the same thing as `COUNT(order_id)`. `COUNT(*)` means "count the number of input rows", while `COUNT(foo)` means "count the number of input rows for which `foo` is non-null".

Comment: I'm using `avg` instead of `sum`+`count`, to be slightly shorter (like in `avg(case when cust_id = 541 then 1 else 0 end)*100`. Is it less efficient?

Answer (score 17):

One solution is to use a nested query-

```
SELECT count(*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM orders)
FROM orders
WHERE cust_id = 541
```

Comment: Unnecessary to involve a subquery for something this trivial.

Comment: +1 for one time queries, this is easier/faster to type and conceptualize than the hobodave's sumif() form.

Comment: No, this is a terrible terrible thing. In PostgreSQL count(*) is not O(1) as it is in MySQL. This query would require two full table scans. This is unnecessary and grows prohibitively worse as the table size increases.

Comment: I should correct that to read "as it is with MyISAM tables in MySQL".

Comment: I'd also like to add: "easier to type" has got to be one of the worst reasons to do something. Unless you're in some sort of competition to complete as much code in as little time as possible.

Comment: hobodave: no, it will not require 2 full table scans. it will require 1 full table scan, and 1 index scan (assuming there is index on cust_id).

Comment: A more simplet one will be 
select cust_id, ( count(*)/(select count(1) from  orders ) * 100 ) from orders group by cust_id;

Comment: @Roopesh: Not quite what he's asking for, but yes that would get the percentage for every customer. +1

Comment: `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` are the same thing. And `hobodave`, your solution is equivalent, since `COUNT(order_id)` means "count the rows for which order_id is non-null". Since order_id is probably never null, it's literally the same thing as `COUNT(*)`. And no, user80168, it won't require a table scan and an index scan. If you're already doing a seq scan there's no need to also scan the index.

Answer (score -3):

```
select abc.item_name, sum(amount) as total
  from (select a.item_id, d.applicablefrom, a.item_name, a.final_item_status, d.rate, c.item_name as sub_item_name,
               b.sub_item_qty as itemqty, (b.sub_item_qty * d.rate) as amount 
          from tblitem_master a,
               tblitem_master c,
               tblitem_bom_master b,
               (select rate, applicablefrom, itemid
                  from tblperiodrates
                 where applicablefrom = (select max(applicablefrom) 
                                           from tblperiodrates
                                          where applicablefrom<='2005-5-18')) as d
         where a.item_id = b.item_id
           And b.sub_item_id = c.item_id
           and b.sub_item_id = d.itemid
           and a.final_item_status='f') as abc
 group by abc.item_name
```

Answer (score -5):

```
select max([order].customerid) customer_id, count(orderid) customer_orders, (select count(orderid) from [order]) as total_orders,
100.0 * (count(orderid))/(select count(orderid) from [order])
from [order] inner join customer
on [order].customerid = customer.customerid
group by [order].customerid
```

To illustrate the flow, I have included more columns than you need to see in the final result set.
Holding the count(order_id) in a temporary variable will be more efficient.
I'm not used to postgres, I hope this works with minimal modification.

Comment: -1 when I get my daily vote count reset. There is no need to do a JOIN and GROUP BY for something as simple as this.

Comment: -1, That is invalid SQL (`[` and `]` are illegal characters in SQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Not illegal in sql server, I did not have a postgresql instance when I responded but tested ok on sql server. And for 2 tables, yes, you'll need a join.

Comment: @keni: then apparently Microsoft violates the SQL standard. The correct character to use for reserved words (in standard SQL and almost every other DBMS) is a double quote, e.g: `"order"`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'll like to +1 this if you share a link to the standard for the records.

Comment: @keni: The book "SQL 99 Complete" has recently been released to the public. The respective chapter is this one: http://kb.askmonty.org/en/sql-language-elements#delimited-identifier