# How to work out Percent in PostgreSQL using Count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to work out the percentage of reads (records) that have a quality score above a certain threshold. I got both values needed using the below queries.

`select count(read_header) from k12_read where quality_score  > 25;`

`select count(read_header) from k12_read;`

I tried this below however it just returns 0.0

`select (select count(*) from k12_read where quality_score >= 25) / (select count(*) from k12_read) * 100.0 as percentage;`

I also [found this online](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1183936) but it also just returned 0.0 when tried.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: try casting the result of the each of the select statements used in the calculation to decimal or something, because the result of count will be integer and the result of the calculation will be < 0 which as an integer will = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres does integer division.  An easy way to fix this is by multiplying by 1.0 or casting the value to a float:

```
select ((select 1.0 * count(*) from k12_read where quality_score >= 25) / 
        (select count(*) from k12_read) * 100.0
       ) as percentage;
```

By the way, I think your query is simpler if you use conditional aggregation with `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when quality_score >= 25 then 100.0 else 0 end)
from k12_read;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Multiplying by 1.0 worked perfectly and thanks for giving a much cleaner solution as well.